# Regex.Split and string.Split not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex, split

I am attempting to split strings using '?' as the delimiter. My code reads data from a CSV file, and certain symbols (like fractions) are not recognized by C#, so I am trying to replace them with a relevant piece of data (bond coupon in this case). I have print statements in the following code (which is embedded in a loop with index variable i) to test the output:

```
string[] l = lines[i][1].Split('?');               
//string[] l = Regex.Split(lines[i][1], @"\?");

System.Console.WriteLine("L IS " + l.Length.ToString() + " LONG");
for (int j = 0; j < l.Length; j++)
    System.Console.WriteLine("L["+ j.ToString() + "] IS " + l[j]);

if (l.Length > 1)
{
    double cpn = Convert.ToDouble(lines[i][12]);
    string couponFrac = (cpn - Math.Floor(cpn)).ToString().Remove(0,1);
    lines[i][1] = l[0].Remove(l[0].Length-1) + couponFrac + l[1]; // Recombine, replacing '?' with CPN
}
```

The issue is that both split methods (`string.Split()` and `Regex.Split()` ) produce inconsistent results with some of the string elements in lines splitting correctly and the others not splitting at all (and thus the question mark is still in the string).

Any thoughts? I've looked at similar posts on split methods and they haven't been too helpful.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of a string, and the result you expect from the split() method?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis For example, the string "TII 0 ? 04/15/15" does not split while "TII 0 ? 01/15/22" is split and recombines into "TII 0.125 01/15/22" appropriately.

Comment: I suspect what you have is a text encoding problem. Those question marks aren't really question marks, but characters that aren't displaying correctly because you don't have the right font loaded. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @JimMischel I came to a similar conclusion as well, but don't know how to fix the problem. The data is a bloomberg report that is exported to excel and then subsequently saved as a csv file. The question marks are replacing those fraction symbols in MS Office.

Comment: When you export to CSV, be sure to export as UTF-8. When you read the data in C#, be sure to use `Encoding.UTF8` when you open the file. You should be able to view the file in Notepad and see the proper characters. If you continue to have trouble, I would suggest posting a new question explaining the conversion process and showing the code you're using to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any trouble parsing the following.

```
var qsv = "now?is?the?time";
var keywords = qsv.Split('?');
keywords.Dump();
```

**screenshot of code and output...**

[image]

**UPDATE:**
There doesn't appear to be any problem with `Split`.  There is a problem somewhere else because in this small scale test it works just fine.  I would suggest you use **LinqPad** to test out these kinds of scenarios small scale.

```
var qsv = "TII 0 ? 04/15/15";
var keywords = qsv.Split('?');
keywords.Dump();

qsv = "TII 0 ? 01/15/22";
keywords = qsv.Split('?');
keywords.Dump();
```

**New updated output:**

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, but I can't imagine what's going on. I think C# is having trouble reading the '?' as if it is some unidentifiable character that prints out to the command line as '?'.

Comment: are you reading the file from disc or getting it from a web service?  If you hardcode the QSV string as a test and it still fails then I would wonder how that could be...  If you don't then you know it's possibly a format problem.

Comment: The data is coming from Bloomberg into an excel file. The question mark is replacing one of those fraction symbols, which i think is not necessarily being read as a '?'.

Comment: dunno if these help but...  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/321197-excel-character-question-mark-box.html  and   http://superuser.com/questions/458606/how-to-search-for-question-mark-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

I had no problem using String.Split. Could you post your input and output?
If at all you could probably use String.Replace to replace your desired '?' with a character that does not occur in the string and then use String.Split on that character to split the resultant string for the same effect. (just a try)

Comment: I used the method lines[i][1].Replace('?', '^') and then tried to split at the '^' but it didn't replace any of the question marks nor did the overloaded string Replace method work.